# How do I log a string in x64dbg?

Tags: disassembly, debuggers, disassemblers

This one should be simple, but I can't figure it out. How do I log a string in x64dbg? I can log the address with a breakpoint but wasn't able to log the actual text.

Comment: Try reading the documentation: http://help.x64dbg.com/en/latest/introduction/Formatting.html

Answer (score 2):

For ASCII strings this should work, I am not sure about Unicode or other character sets.

Right click the breakpoint and select edit.

In the "Log Text" box, put,

```
String is {s:eax}
```

With eax containing the address of the string.

Comment: It will work for any kind of string that is automatically detected in the x64dbg GUI.

Answer (score 1):

The `{s:EAX}` works fine, but we have more options than that, for example:
`{utf16@RCX}`, `{utf8@RCX}`, `{ascii@RCX}` can log the given string with a certain encoding